# React router dom v-6 not working on build version

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, netlify

I'm working on a chat application that has some paths like below

```
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<WelcomeScreen />} />
                <Route path="channels" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="channels/:id" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/" />} />
            </Routes>
```

Once the users are authenticated, they are redirected from welcome screen to home page that has all the chats which is on `/channels`. So if a user were to access `/channels` or in the case of 404, I redirected to the `/` path.

Everything works fine when I run it on localhost but once I host it on netlify and when I refresh at `/channels` instead of redirecting I get a 404 message and `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/" />} />` Doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what's the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `<BrowserRouter>` to `<HashRouter>`. It lets refreshing individual page without 404 error.  
Reference: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#reference

#### Update

If you are using Netlify you can do this to be able to use `<BrowserRouter>` and avoid hash `#` in the routes

Create a file named `_redirects` with following content in your build folder

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Comment: Thanks it works now but I'm getting a hash in the url. ```http://localhost:3000/#/channels```. Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: you can still use BrowserRouter and avoid using HashRouter by making some changes in server side, by pointing all incoming requests to index.html and let react-router-dom handle the routing on client side

Answer (score 0):

you have different solutions, one of them is to put the following in the htaccess:

```html
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^c(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

If you still get an error, put your real url in the homepage:"", of your package.json, example: https://wildreds.es/, so the browserRouter will be able to detect you well, take care crack.